# Flutter Data Model Doesn't Update When Amplify Pulled

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm using the AWS GraphQL database for my Flutter application. When I create my database on the AWS panel and type **'amplify pull'** on the Flutter project terminal, there is no problem initially. All data models are created automatically successfully.

The problem is, that I have created new data models on GraphQL and when I type **'amplify pull'** the **'schema.graphql'** file updates on the Flutter project but the new models don't come with that.

How can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-generate all your models using this command

```
amplify codegen models
```

For more information [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#generate-todo-model-class)